# How to iterate a JSON array in typescript in HTML?

Tags: json, loops, typescript, angular5, ngfor

I have a **snippets of JSON array** as shown below:

```
[{
        "auction_number": "015",
        "email": "pete@abc.com",
        "first_name": "Peter",
        "last_name": "Dan",
        "table": 0,
        "id": "015"
    },
    {
        "auction_number": "024",
        "email": "dan@gog.com",
        "first_name": "Dan",
        "last_name": "Fain",
        "table": 0,
        "id": "024"
    }
]
```

**Typescript Code:**
The **typescript** **(ts)** for the **above JSON array** is shown below. Here `attendees` is an array object.

```
attendees: Attendee[];
 constructor(public authService: AuthService) {
    const str = localStorage.getItem("attendees");
    if(str) {
      this.attendees = JSON.parse(str);
      console.log(str);
    }
  }
```

**HTML Code:**

The **HTML code** which I have used  in order to iterate everything from the **JSON array (in the typescript code)** is shown below. For some reasons, it is not able to iterate `attendees` in the HTML.

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of attendees">
   <td class="left">{{ attendees.first_name }} {{ attendees.last_name }}</td>
   <td class="number1">250</td>
   <td class="table1">{{attendees.table}}</td>
   <td class="right-bill">Bill</td>
</tr>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the **HTML code above** so that I am successfully able to iterate `attendees` array. I tried using **ngfor directive** but somehow it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You should reference fields in each row as `row.first_name` because you set each attendee as `let row of attendees`. The variable you defined is `row`.

Comment: I tried this   `<tr *ngFor="let row of attendee">
                    <td class="left">{{row.first_name}}</td>
                    <td class="number1">250</td>
                    <td class="table1">{{row.table}}</td>
                    <td class="right-bill">Bill</td>
                </tr>` but I didn't see any change.

Comment: It should be `let row of attendees`. I modified that. Sorry for the typo above.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the parent loop again, you should access only the elements of row

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of attendees">
   <td class="left">{{ row .first_name }} {{ row .last_name }}</td>
   <td class="number1">250</td>
   <td class="table1">{{attendees.table}}</td>
   <td class="right-bill">Bill</td>
</tr>
```